# Youtube Videos in tableview cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, youtube

I currently have a tableview with YouTube videos embedded inside of the custom cells.

I did this because from my research it seemed like the only way to allow the videos to load without leaving my application.

The problem is this

The thumbnails take a while to load. As I scroll down the list of videos, it keeps having to load the thumbnails. If I scroll back up, it tries to load the video thumbnails yet again.

Has anyone got any suggestions on either better ways of doing this, or ways of getting the table cells to keep the data and not replace it?

My code looks like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

YouTubeCell *cell = (YouTubeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell ==nil){

    cell = [[[YouTubeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

}
NSDictionary *dic = [youTubeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell updateCellData:dic];
return cell;

}

-(void)updateCellData:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
NSDictionary *tempDic = [dict objectForKey:@"video"];
self.titleLbl.text = [tempDic objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *viewCountStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views -",[tempDic objectForKey:@"viewCount"]];
viewCountLbl.text = viewCountStr;
uploadedDateLbl.text = [tempDic objectForKey:@"uploaded"];

NSDictionary *videoDic = [tempDic objectForKey:@"player"];
NSString *videoStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[videoDic objectForKey:@"default"]]; 

NSString *embedHTML = 
@"<html><head>\
<body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

// videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 100, 60)]; initialzed in ///initwithstyle of cell

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoStr, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cache your loaded images.

One approach could be to create for example a mutable dictionary, in which you store your images with keys unique to your `UITableViewCells`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you retrieve the corresponding image by calling for example `[dictionary objectForKey:uniquecellidentifier]`. If it returns `nil`, you know the image has not yet been loaded and you should create a request to do so. As soon as the loading has finished, you store the image in the dictionary (`[dictionary setObject:image forKey:uniquecellidentifier]`

This should get you a more specific idea:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    if([dictionary objectForKey:cellid]){
        NSLog(@"Retrieving value for %@: %@", cellid, [dictionary objectForKey:cellid]);
        cell.textLabel.text=[dictionary objectForKey:cellid];
        //Show image from dictionary
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Now value set for %@.", cellid);
        [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testvalue%@", cellid] forKey:cellid]; //Save image in dictionary
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Loaded";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Create an `NSMutableDictionary`named "dictionary" in your header file and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Header file:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

This will result in the following behaviour:
The first time, your cell is displayed, it shows "Loaded". In all subsequent appearances it will display its set value.